# I am having difficulty finding, making a triple integral of the space z< |x-y|. Can someone recommend a technique most effective fore such things?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having difficulty finding, making a triple integral of the space $z< |x-y|$. Can someone recommend a technique most effective fore such things?

I try to somehow draw the graph and see the bounderies for each axis from there, but i can't seem to get the right answer. By book get the result:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}dx \int_{x}^{\infty}dy \int_{0}^{y-x}dz+ \int_{0}^{\infty}dy \int_{y}^{\infty}dx \int_{0}^{x-y}dz$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that result from the book, there have to be more conditions $x,y,z\geq 0$. Then you can consider the $z$-limits of two parts
$$z=
\begin{cases}x-y, & \text{if } x-y>0, \text{ or } y<x\\
y-x, & \text{if } x-y<0, \text{ or } y>x\end{cases}$$
Imagine the following picture with $z$ value folded upward from both sides of the line:

[image]

So the limits of $z$ are $0$ and $x-y$ for the lower region. The $xy$ limits can be figured out with the picture extending to infinity on both $x$ and $y$.

The limits of $z$ for the upper region are $0$ and $y-x$ based on the above equations.